# PHP Array Element Not Getting Put In String (Error)

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

The following code doesn't work as I expected...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password="+$alphas[$x]+"&submit=yes");
```

The $alphas[$x] part doesn't seem to work by putting the letter in the string. A couple lines below that I echo $alphas[$x] and that works perfectly.

For example, if I change the first line of code to...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password=j&submit=yes");
```

It works perfectly as expected, so therefore I think $alpahs[$x] isn't putting the letter in the string like it should.

```
$content = "7";
$x = 0;
$alphas = array_merge(range("A", "Z"), range("a", "z"));

while($x < 52) {
print_r($alphas[$x]);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/Demo/form.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password="+$alphas[$x]+"&submit=yes");
$content=curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;
echo "Pass: ";
echo $alphas[$x];
echo "<br>";
$x++;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The period is the string concatenation operator, not the plus sign:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password=".$alphas[$x]."&submit=yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert variables into a double-quoted string using the following syntax:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password={$alphas[$x]}&submit=yes");
```